# How to use output variable or sample variable in Beanshell Jmeter?

Tags: http, asp.net-web-api, jmeter, beanshell

I have http request and I am using Beanshell postprocesser to get my response data in variable , as I want to store my response data in output file.

in Beanshell postprocesser:

```
String result_1 = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
vars.put("result_1", "result_1");
```

Here: result_1 is my sample_variable in user.properties file

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
sample_variables=test_id,result_1
```

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to save the response into the variable you need to remove quotation marks around `result_1` like:

   ```
   String result_1 = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
   vars.put("result_1", result_1);
   ```
2. You need to switch JMeter result file to XML format as response data cannot be stored in CSV mode, therefore you need this line in *user.properties*

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
   ```

Also given you are already storing response data by this property `jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true` you don't need Sample Variables step.

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell)